# assign null but still remains old value in vue js v-text-field

Tags: vue.js

```
<v-radio-group row v-model="fields.destination" @change="changeDestination">
<v-radio>.....
<v-radio-group>
<v-text-field v-model="fields.name"></v-text-field>
```

in changeDestination function

```
changeDestination(){ 
  this.fields.name = null;
  console.log(this.fields.name) 
}
```

when I enter some value to v-text-field, and then click radio, textfield still remains old value, it does not turn to blank(null) but when console.log(this.fields.name) in changeDestionation function, it outputs null. why? and how can I solve to assign null?

Comment: can you try : methods: {
  changeDestination() {
    this.fields.name = null;
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      console.log(this.fields.name);
    });
  }
}

Comment: @EfrosIonelu yes I have tried, it still shows null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's probably because you change a value in a nested state and change the data type of this field. vue does not like that. you either have to keep it a string or you can explicitly force reactivity like this:

```
Vue.set(this.fields, 'name', null);
```

or access `$set` on the vue component with same syntax

```
this.$set(this.fields, 'name', null);
```

Comment: solved with your way.thank you